# Typical Question Sandbox code is working Production not working uncheck all checkbox

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

visualforce page:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}" />
       <td bgcolor="#CC0000"><apex:inputcheckbox value="{!child.batchObj.confirm_Order__c}" /></td>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
    });
    </script>
```

I have written my all include javascript .this code want to deselect checkbox when page load .Strange thing is is very well working in sandbox.but this is not working in production.

Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: did u chk if u hv the jquery resources in production as well ? use the dev tools / firebug in ur browser to see if you find any script errors when the vf page loads.

Comment: both sandbox and production in the same browser .how the script will fail only one production

Answer (score 2):

This is a jQuery [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514566/checkbox-set-to-checked-false-not-working) and has nothing to do with Sandbox or production. Try this

Don't put checked="false"

You only put checked="checked" for valid XHTML, otherwise you'd do

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

The browser doesn't care what value is assigned to checked attribute, as soon as it sees checked in the checkbox input tag, it's flagged as checked.